# How to get result from 2 mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i want to get results from 2 tables 'altitle' and 'scroll100' where live = 1 delete = 0 and kategori = 1 or 9 or 30. I actualy have to get just from one table can anyone help me please ?

```
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM  `altitle` WHERE  `live` = 1 AND `delete` = 0 AND `kategori` = 1 ORDER BY  `id` DESC ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: What is the schema of your both tables? What is the link between them?

Comment: The schema is the same and they are on same database just different tables.

Comment: are the tables related at all, e.g. via a foreign key? if they're two completely different tables, you'd need two queries, otherwise a simple JOIN should do...

Comment: Marc B tables have same structure just differenc charactere limit on php when add the text. And i want to show Breaking News and Latest News from tables altitle and scroll100 where breaking news have category id 1 and latest news have category id 9 and in the scroll100 latest news have category id 30. Strange architecture i know but its television to show ticker on tv :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your comment, you should put your two tables in the FROM clause:

```php
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM  `altitle` a, `scroll100` s 
                        WHERE  a.`live` = 1
                        AND a.`delete` = 0 
                        AND (a.`kategori` = 1
                        OR a.`kategori` = 9
                        OR a.`kategori` = 30)
                        AND s.`live` = 1
                        AND s.`delete` = 0 
                        AND (s.`kategori` = 1
                        OR s.`kategori` = 9
                        OR s.`kategori` = 30)
                        ORDER BY  a.`id` DESC ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is a strange architecture, you know.

Comment: Happy thank you for your answer but one think more a.`kategori` = 1 can i add OR a.`kategori` = 9 ? I mean kategori = 1 OR 9 ?

Comment: Of course you can. I have just edited my answer.